# Browsers only load one font

Tags: css, font-face

Part of my CSS reads:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Clarendon";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    src: url("fonts/Fontspring-DEMO-Clarendon-Light.otf") format("opentype");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Clarendon";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    src: url("fonts/Fontspring-DEMO-Clarendon-Medium.otf") format("opentype");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Clarendon";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 700;
    src: url("fonts/Fontspring-DEMO-Clarendon-Bold.otf") format("opentype");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Clarendon";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 800;
    src: url("fonts/Fontspring-DEMO-Clarendon-Xbold.otf") format("opentype");
}
```

but browsers only load one font.

- If I comment all but one font: only the specified font gets loaded. (As per dev tools Network tab)
- If 2 or more fonts are defined: it's always `fonts/Fontspring-DEMO-Clarendon-Medium.otf`.
- I tried both Chrome and Firefox. Same behaviour.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are all of those fonts being used on a single page?

Comment: You wrote "being used on a single page" and I hit on the word "used". Of course, not all fonts were downloaded — they weren't being *used* yet. As soon as I created some test styles using each of the fonts, I discovered that they were now actually being loaded. *facepalm*

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Fonts in @font-face declarations are only loaded if they're actually used on the page.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!